Spike Prime Blocks vs Python for FLL competition
Our team has used blocks to code our robot in FLL for a while. I heard that python gives more flexibility on code. But I just don't understand since they are exact same functions and block is easier to code. Why is it more flexible? Should i switch to python?
I have checked out some python functions and they seemed same to me. Actually more complex but does the same thing.

"They are exact same functions and block" as long as you just want to combine the blocks that Spike makes available to you by default. On the other hand, I agree that "Python gives more flexibility" as it enables you -for example- to define your own classes or rely on external libraries, which comes in handy to achieve more complex results. Maybe you should edit the question to detail the case at hand, propose your Python implementation, and describe the parts that are to be improved/debugged.
